# Redirect to url in new tab from plsql code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

On button click action "Redirect to URL" I call below script:

```
javascript:var a = window.open('f?p=300:99:&APP_SESSION.::NO:105:PARAM_1,PARAM_2,PARAM_3:&P99_PARAM_1.,P99_PARAM_2,&P99_PARAM_3.');
```

Is it possible call this from PLSQL in oracle apex application eg.

```
begin
   //call here
   //htp.p(??
end;
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a simple branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL for this. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-D5A736C6-BA1E-41B5-AF95-D43AC9805D2F.htm#AEAPI2324).
Your pl/sql would then be (bind var syntax :P1_ITEM because it is pl/sql):

```
BEGIN
  apex_util.redirect_url(p_url => 'f?p=300:99:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO:105:PARAM_1,PARAM_2,PARAM_3:'||:P99_PARAM_1||','||:P99_PARAM_2||','||:P99_PARAM_3);
END;
```

Comment: This is redirecting to the URL, However it is redirecting to same tab but not creating new tab. Please suggest to redirect to new tab not in same tab.

Comment: What you are asking is not a redirect - URL Redirect (also referred to as URL Forwarding) is a technique which is used to redirect your domain's visitors to a different URL. You are asking how to open an url in a new window, that cannot be done using this technique. I suggest you file a new question.