# Open url in new tab apex_util.redirect_url

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Is it possible open url in new tab from pl sql eg.

```
begin
apex_util.redirect_url(p_url => 'fp=10:111:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO:105:NAME,P_1,P_2:'||:P111_P1||',TEST,'||TEST1); 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not from PL/SQL. apex_util.redirect_url will send an HTTP Location response header which the browser will follow in the current tab.

This question seems related to this one, no?
[Redirect to url in new tab from plsql code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835837/redirect-to-url-in-new-tab-from-plsql-code)

Ultimately, if you want to open a new tab you need to do it from JavaScript or an anchor element.

Why do you want to do this from PL/SQL? What is the timing point of the PL/SQL?

If it was on submit, then the current tab will need to show something, no? Whatever it shows, that page could then open the new tab on load.

Comment: McGham before redirect to url in plsql I have loop where generate parameter for URL. From plsql I bind filed eg. :P10_PARAM := 'some value'. After bind filed I need call redirect to new tab.

Comment: You haven't told me the timing of the PL/SQL. When is it executing?

Comment: McGham I'm create PROCESS, when button is pressed I call this process. 
Maybe is this wrong way, I don't know how on one button click call this. I'm try with two dynamic action first (loop) and second (redirect to url javascript) but not working url is not generated. eg.  https://ibb.co/4SPbHYN

Comment: My last name has an "n" on the end, not an "m". :) It sounds like the PL/SQL is only being used to generate the URL (not doing any other kind of DML or whatever). In that case, you should be able to something similar to what I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493605/apex-row-selector-part-2/58495118 Have a look at that and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that example was opening a modal within the same tab. In your case, it would be even simpler because you would just get plain URL back from the PL/SQL Ajax process (not a JavaScript snippet). So your `success` function would just need to access `data.url` to open the modal using `apex.navigation.openInNewWindow`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/apex.navigation.html#.openInNewWindow

Comment: sorry for lastname, I will see example from above links.